# Not able to evict the associated entiries of Hibernate 2nd level cache - ehcache

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I am using Hibernate 4.17 and use ehcache as second level cache. In the definition of hbm file, I declare the cache at the class level.

```
<class name="com.test.Program" table="program" mutable="false">

    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
 ....
```

I have 1-to-many association defined as follows

```
 <list name="parameters" cascade="none" batch-size="100">
    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
    <key column="program_oid"/>
    <index column="sequence" />
    <one-to-many class="com.test.ProgramParameter"/>
  </list>
```

I have a region defined for main class - Program in the ehcache.xml. The issue is whenever I evict the 2nd level cache using

```
HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictEntityRegion("com.test.Program");
```

All the entities of **com.test.Program** are evicted but not **com.test.Program.parameters**
Further more, If I try to evict com.test.Program.parameters entities like above, I get the exception "Unknown Entity".

How do I evict the entities of associated class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictCollectionRegion("com.test.Program.parameters");
```

The cache setting on the `parameters` list will store just the identifiers of the entities in that list in a separate [collection cache](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-collection-cache-work/), using the identifier of the parent Program entity as the key.

The `ProgramParameter` entities themselves will not be cached unless you have a corresponding cache setting on that entity, e.g.

```
<class name="com.test.ProgramParameter" table="program_parameter" mutable="false">

    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
 ....
```

Whenever you use a collection cache, you should cache the entities as well otherwise Hibernate will still need to fetch each entity in the collection from the database.

Comment: Actually I tried to evict com.test.Program.parameters (question is edited) and got an error. However, retrieving all region names shows this one as region. I also have cache set, like you showed above, for ProgramParameters.

Comment: I think it should be `evictCollectionRegion()`. Have updated.

Comment: Perfect.This is exactly I was looking for. Thx